# How to conditionally render a prop initialized as an empty object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My application has a user input a query to make a request to the Pokemon API and the response is rendered. Prior to the user making a request, it shows `No Pokemon yet, please submit a Pokemon`.

I initialized `pokemonCharacter` as an empty object being passed to the `PokemonInfo` component. However, my conditional render logic is not working.

Please let me know how to solve this. https://codesandbox.io/s/pokedex-5j1jf

The following are my failed attempts.
Attempt #1

```
let myDiv;
if (pokemonCharacter && pokemonCharacter.length > 0) {
  myDiv = <div>
    <p>{pokemonCharacter.name}</p>
    <img src={pokemonCharacter.sprites.front_default} alt="pokemon" />
  </div>
} else {
  myDiv = <p>No Pokemon yet, please submit a Pokemon!</p>
}
return ({myDiv})
```

Attempt #2

```
{(pokemonCharacter && pokemonCharacter.length > 0) ?
  <div>
    <p>{pokemonCharacter.name}</p>
    <img src={pokemonCharacter.sprites.front_default} alt="pokemon" />
  </div>
: <p>No Pokemon yet, please submit a Pokemon!</p>}
```

Attempt #3

```
    const list = pokemonCharacter => {
    if (!pokemonCharacter) {
      return null;
    }
    if (!pokemonCharacter.length) {
      return <p>No Pokemon yet, please submit a Pokemon!</p>
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{pokemonCharacter.name}</p>
          <img src={pokemonCharacter.sprites.front_default} alt="pokemon" />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  return (
    {list}
  );
```

Comment: use the loader. check if it is false the display the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by checking if `pokemonCharacter.name` is truthy in the `PokemonInfo` component, as opposed to just checking if `pokemonCharacter` the object as a whole is truthy.

```
     {pokemonCharacter.name ?
        <div>
          <p>{pokemonCharacter.name}</p>
          <img src={pokemonCharacter.sprites.front_default} alt="pokemon" />
        </div>
      : <p>No Pokemon yet, please submit a Pokemon!</p>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you are checking the loading status, just check if the status is false or not then display the component.

```
{ loading 
  ? <p>Loading...</p> 
  : <PokemonInfo pokemonCharacter={pokemonCharacter} />
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not conditionally rendering.